# Google Sheets Lock Apply Three Different Range Protection With One Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create 3 different protections in Google Sheet by running one script. The script should run automatically daily at 2 AM ie. time based tirgger. Below example will give more clarity on the question. Am also attaching a sample sheet with the desired result.

**E.g** There are 8 columns in my sample sheet having data in different cells of each column. In column B i.e. column 2 the last row with data is row no. 14.

I want to create 3 different protection in this Worksheet (i) Protection 1 for Column B and C (ii) Protection 2 for Column E and (iii) Protection 3 for Column G and H. All protections will start from row no. 2 of all these ranges and will end at the last row of column B having data. In the sample sheet last row in column B with data is row no. 14 hence protection in each of the above 3 ranges will be from row No. 2 to row No. 14. The three different protections after application of the script will be (1) Protection 1:- B2:C14 (2) Protection 2:- E2:E14 and (3) Protection 3:- G2:H14.

The time based trigger is 2 AM daily hence every day the script will run and will first remove the old protection and then create new protection considering updated last row of column B i.e. column 2.

Further the protection should cover 2 editors i.e. these two ids abc@abc.com and xyz@xyz.com will be allowed to edit the protected range.

Link to sample sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p_-z5I4T_5wiwXAxMtd_wmUFSamtGE5tPtkpbTAeBWs/edit#gid=0

Any solution on above will be appreciated.

Comment: In AppsScript, you can add protection to a particular range and also add editors to it - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection. Here's a proposed solution -
Every day 2 AM when the script runs, remove all protections. Then calculate the last row num in col B having data and based on it get the three ranges. Add protection to the three ranges separately and add editors to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion: use `getRangeList()` to identify and lock specific ranges

@ab.it.gcp's proposed solution is one way to accomplish your goal. For a more simplified approach, you can use the `getRangeList()` method and a `forEach` loop to lock columns `B:C`, `E`, and `G:H` based on column `B`'s last value.

**EDIT:** I've updated the script to demonstrate how to add editors to the protected ranges.

Do try running this script as a time-based trigger:

```
function rangeLock() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Change the sheet name if necessary
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 2, sourceSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var editors = ['abc@abc.com', 'xyz@xyz.com'] //Update this array with the editors' actual email addresses.
  var lastRow = sourceRange.filter(x => x != '').length - 1; //calculates the number of non-empty rows on column B

  //The three variables below gets the A1 notation of the ranges to lock,based on Column B's last row with value
  var colBC = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 2, lastRow, 2).getA1Notation(); 
  var colE = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 5, lastRow).getA1Notation();
  var colGH = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 7, lastRow, 2).getA1Notation();
  

  var rangesToLock = sourceSheet.getRangeList([colBC, colE, colGH]).getRanges(); //returns the specific ranges to lock
  var currentProtection = sourceSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE) //Gets the sheet's existing protected ranges.

  //if there are existing protected ranges, the if statement below will remove it prior to protecting the identified ranges.
  if(currentProtection.length > 0) currentProtection.forEach(p => p.remove());

  rangesToLock.forEach(range => {
    protectedRange = range.protect()
    protectedRange.removeEditors(protectedRange.getEditors());
    protectedRange.addEditors(editors);
    if (protectedRange.canDomainEdit()) protectedRange.setDomainEdit(false);
  })
}
```

### References:

- [getRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String))
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: @ DuuEyn Thank you very much for the super fast, perfect and excellent solution, it works as desired to protect the range. However, as regards  adding email ids to protected range as editors there is an issue i.e. all the editors of spread sheet are assigned edit access to the protected range, this does not solves the second purpose. Actually only few email ids as specified in the script should be allowed edit access to the protected range. As your solution addresses first part i.e. locking the range, hence am closing this question and posting a separate question for this issue.

Comment: @ DuuEy as quoted by you in the reply "//Feel free to add editors inside this loop if needed.", in that section I added" rangesToLock.removeEditors(rangesToLock.getEditors());
rangesToLock.addEditors(editors);
if (rangesToLock.canDomainEdit()) rangesToLock.setDomainEdit(false);}  and also defined in Editor the required email ides but this is not working to add editors email ids in the protected range. Can you pl. explain how to add email ids for editors in code?

Comment: Hi @Essem, I've updated the answer to demonstrate how to add editors to the protected range. For any follow-up questions though, I recommend posting a new question so that other members of the community can take a look at it as well.

Comment: thank you very much for the perfect solution, and will definitely take not of your suggestion of posting new question for followup queries.