# Google App Script Add Editors To Protected Range Giving Error

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to Google App script and also to this community. Apologize in advance if language of question is not as per the expectations of the community. I will be happy to provide any further clarification o the question if required.

I am using below script to add editors to protected range, the scripts work fine for protecting the range but the last part of the script which is supposed to remove all the editors from the protected range and than add few specific email ids only as editors gives error. The part of script because of which the error is produced is highlighted in bold i.e. between **....**.

```
function rangeLock() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var editors = ["abc@abc.com", "xyz@xyz.com"]; 
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 2, sourceSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
var lastRow = sourceRange.filter(x => x != '').length - 1; 
var colBC = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 2, lastRow, 2).getA1Notation(); 
var colE = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 5, lastRow).getA1Notation();
var colGH = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 7, lastRow, 2).getA1Notation();
var rangesToLock = sourceSheet.getRangeList([colBC, colE, colGH]).getRanges(); 
var currentProtection = sourceSheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE) 
if(currentProtection.length > 0) currentProtection.forEach(p => p.remove());
rangesToLock.forEach(range => {
    range.protect();});
**  rangesToLock.removeEditors(rangesToLock.getEditors());
rangesToLock.addEditors(editors);
if (rangesToLock.canDomainEdit()) rangesToLock.setDomainEdit(false);**}
```

I tried the solutions available in this community and other resource but could not find a perfect solution to my issue.

Thanks to the community members in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets Lock Apply Three Different Range Protection With One Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78089179/google-sheets-lock-apply-three-different-range-protection-with-one-script)